# Effectively assign the same value to several indices of a matrix

Tags: matrix, array

I want to assign the same value to several indices by using just one command. I could do this for every index separately:

```
c = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}];
c[[2, 3]] = a;
c[[4, 1]] = a;
c[[6, 3]] = a;
```

How could I do this easier in one line? An approach like

```
c[[{2,3},{4,1},{6,3}]]=a
```

does not work.

Comment: `c = MapAt[a &, c, {{2, 3}, {4, 1}, {6, 3}}]`?

Comment: or `c = ReplacePart[c, {{2, 3}, {4, 1}, {6, 3}} -> a]`?

Comment: or `(c[[##]] = a) & @@@ {{2, 3}, {4, 1}, {6, 3}}`

Comment: Is `c` always a `ConstantArray`? If so, check `SparseArray`.